Distribution of random variable when lower/upper limit is known
Let $X$ be an i.i.d. random discrete variable in $[0,255]$. That is, $\mathrm{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{256}$ and the distribution looks something like

What is $\mathrm{P}(X=x\mid X > 127)$? I imagine the i.i.d. distribution is now compressed into $[128,255]$ and it looks like this:

Correct me if I'm wrong though!
Further, I have a more complicated case where I have a non-iid distribution for my random variable. Imagine something like

But if this is again bounded by a lower limit like 128? Is the same distribution now squeezed within $[128,255]$? I'm having a hard time finding an intuition around it.

You're misusing the term "i.i.d." here. What you've called "i.i.d." and "non-i.i.d." distributions are properly called "uniform" and "non-uniform" distributions.

Really? It seems to me to fit the definition. Could you elaborate?

The term "i.i.d." ("mutually independent and identically distributed") refers to a collective property of two or more random variables. Here you have only one r.v., so it is nonsensical to say "an i.i.d. random variable" or "a non-iid distribution for my random variable". (Your 1st and 3rd pictures show uniform and non-uniform distributions, but you refer to them as "i.i.d." and "non-iid", respectively.)

(... cont'd) Also, note that if we were to consider the definition of "i.i.d." as being trivially satisfied by a collection of just one r.v., then saying that such a single r.v. is "i.i.d." is to say nothing at all about it -- because in that case every such size-one collection is "i.i.d."


Let $X$ be an i.i.d. random discrete variable in $[0,255]$. That is, $\mathrm{P}(X=x)=\frac{1}{256}$ and looks something like ...

Yes.  Well, the plot should not be a continuous line, but a series of points.  However, that just might not be visible at that resolution.
The support covers the integer parts of $[0,255]$, which may be written as $[[0,255]]$.

What is $\mathrm{P}(X=x\mid X > 127)$? I imagine the i.i.d. distribution is now compressed into $[128,255]$ and it looks like this:

"Compressed" is not quite the right term, as none of the points in the conditioned support are squeezed closer together; they are still integer-valued.
But yes, the conditional distribution has a support over $[[128,255]]$ and has a mass of $1/(255-128+1)$ at each point.$$\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>127) = \dfrac{1}{128}\,\mathbf 1_{x\in[[128,255]]}$$

... But if this is again bounded by a lower limit like 128? Is the same distribution now squeezed within [128,255] ? I'm having a hard time finding an intuition around it.

And here is why 'compressed' is not the correct term; rather it is 'truncated' and 'normalised'.  The shape over the truncated support ($[[128,255]]$) remains the same but will be scaled by a normalising constant.   The shape over the rest of the support does not contribute to the conditioned distribution at all.
$$\mathsf P(X=x\mid X>127) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=x)\,\mathbf 1_{x\in[[288,255]]}}{\mathsf P(X>127)}$$
